# How to make input work only on drag should not respond on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am in need of a input type range work like iOS slider, where onclick should not trigger. And it should trigger only when dragged. Both `onInput()` and `onChange()` events are triggered when clicked on input range.

So the test case is that onclick should be disabled but where as ondrag should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

HTML

```
<div id="slider">

</div>
<div id="val">

</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#slider').slider({
    min:1,
    max:100,
    stop: unlock
  });

  function unlock(event, slider){
    $('#val').text(slider.value);
    if(slider.value <100){
    } else {
      alert('unlocked');
    }
  }
});
```

And live **[DEMO](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=fd87038422ab0b05e614385535114134)**

Comment: its working for onclick() know. my requirement is it should work on drag only. no onclick event

Comment: Did you tried the demo ? if you drag it till 100 it fires and alert if you dont drag till 100 nothing happens. its not onclick, it work on release.

Comment: If you want to fire it every single point you drag, then change the 'stop' to 'slide' in the slide function.

Comment: I quite didn't get your answer. I've seen your demo. Its not What I want. I want to disable onclick event on slider. But on drag it should work.

Comment: what you gonna do on drag that you dont want to trigger on click?

Comment: just increment a counter min:0 max:100, But the requirement is like that.

Comment: then you gonna use slide: function, instead of stop in my code.